# How to append new value to xts object without creating a new one

Tags: r, xts

I have an xts object, for example

```
ts=xts(seq(10),seq(Sys.Date(),Sys.Date()+10,length.out=10))
```

and need to add a new point, for example

```
(Sys.Date()+11, 11)
```

I have tried

```
ts[Sys.Date()+11] <- 11
```

but it doesnt work. I would prefer to avoid creating a new xts object. Is there an elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `c` or `rbind` on an `xts` object to append row-wise:

```
c(ts, xts(11, Sys.Date()+11))
```

**EDIT :**

Note that this produces a warning `mismatched types: converting objects to numeric`.  To remove the warning, first coerce the value to numeric, e.g:

```
c(ts, xts(as.integer(11), Sys.Date()+11))

           [,1]
2011-12-01    1
2011-12-02    2
2011-12-03    3
2011-12-04    4
2011-12-05    5
2011-12-06    6
2011-12-07    7
2011-12-08    8
2011-12-09    9
2011-12-11   10
2011-12-12   11
```

Comment: I get the following warning, do you also have it?  `Warning message:
In c.xts(ts, xts(11, Sys.Date() + 11)) :
  mismatched types: converting objects to numeric`

Comment: @LouisChiffre I have edited the answer.  You can remove the warning by explicitly coercing the data to integer, before passing to `xts`